# Runtime error when rebuild visual studio 2013 project with visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a C++ project,run fine when using visual studio 2013.
When use visual studio 2015, project is still build fine, but when running error: "the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b".
I know this is a very general question, any ideas? What should i check?

Comment: Please "Rebuild all". And check the libraries that you are linking. It looks like you link against a library that was build with the previous toolset and requires older DLLs which are not present on your (new?) system. When rebuilding please also check which toolset your projects are using and that all projects use the same.

Comment: It is on one pc and they both set the correct environment variable. The only thing is that ".lib" to the project have not been rebuilt, can the problem be there?

Comment: Yes that can be the problem.